# Php Encoding Type Changing Automatically

Tags: encoding

Hi there please excuse any ignorance on my behalf as I am a complete beginner!

Last week my software application stopped working because of a problem in the webcore (a php file where all my functions are stored). When I looked in the webcore all the { and some other characters had changed to question marks. Today the same thing happened but the { and other characters had changed to ã and õ. I'm guessing this is something to do with the encoding type the file is saved it but when I double checked it was saved as UTF-8 it made no difference.

Does any one know how to change it all back? And does any one have any suggestions as to why this might be happening? Could we have a bug?

Thank you very  much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is your text editor. Change your text editor: Sublime Text 2.